# Synonym for 'GUI' for non-technical people?

Tags: terminology, novice-users

Does anyone know a good synonym for 'GUI' that non-technical people will understand? Or a simple sentence explaining it that still won't scare them off?

I mean this in the context of, for example, letting the user choose between an "Simple GUI" and "Advanced GUI" setting.

Comment: Maybe just drop the abbreviation and call it the interface?

Comment: I still think the answer I gave applies.  Just call it "simple" and "advanced", or simple and advanced mode.  No need to mention GUI or interface.

Comment: I'd call this "advanced view" or perhaps "advanced mode" - that is, assuming your users didn't get it when you just use "simple" and "advanced" without a noun, which might work.

Comment: "The buttons and icons and thingamabobs that you click and tap on and stuff"

Comment: "Visual interface between human and computer"

Comment: Most programs just have a checkbox for "advanced settings" in the settings menu, which defaults to off.

Comment: Using the word "interface" in the context of a graphical application is both redundant and ambiguous. It can be confusing because of its generic meaning: a network interface has nothing to do with user interaction, but it's still called an interface. Which is why the use of the word "interface" in "user interface" requires the qualificator.

Better concentrate on the utility of the choice behind the name of the control. 'Settings' and 'mode' are the usual choices, as they're generic, but not too ambiguous in the context of a usual application.

Comment: Sometimes more specific names can be necessary, though. For example, when you have several kinds of settings for two different but adjacent contexts in an application (say, a complex form), which can be confused. In this case you definitely want to mention the distinction, e.g. 'advanced network config', 'simple profile settings' (where 'profile' means 'user profile'). But then usually such contexts may need other means of separation (tabs, pages etc.), which make such specification unnecessary.

Comment: How you explain it depends on who you are explaining it to. Find whatever they relate to and explain it in terms they will understand. Some may interpret Top Layer or User Interface or Visual etc. all differently.

Comment: Why not just call it "User Interface"? basic/default/minimal/primary User Interface vs advance/cluttered/secondary User Interface ?

Comment: How about "The thing you click on. Do you want to see more or less things to click on?"

Comment: It's the GUI interface. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What about "the visual part of the application, i.e. its buttons, text boxes and other visual elements"?

In a more detailed form, you would also include that it handles:

- The process of displaying the elements to the user through a screen,
- The interaction of the user with those elements (most commonly known as events, but it's not limited to events).

Note that non-technical people understand quite well what interface is. This makes it pretty easy to understand what is user interface. The most difficult part is the "G": most non-technical would assume that GUI is the only user interface which exists, and console-style interface is not an interface at all.

Comment: _"Note that non-technical people understand quite well what interface is"_ So 'Interface'. Yeah, I guess that will work. Thanks :-)

Comment: "Interface" is a reasonably technical word in and of itself.  It's better to [lie to children/grandparents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) and just call the GUI the "program" as per Dan's answer.

Comment: @NickT, I don't think it even counts as a lie to children.  It's not an oversimplification, just communicating the information that is relevant in context.  For example, if I said "this car is powerful", it would be an accurate statement, even though technically it is the *engine* that is powerful.

Answer (score 137):

There is little need even to explain the idea of *interface* to users of the program.  To them, the program **is** the interface.

Don't say "the GUI of the program does X".  Just say "the program does X".

Don't say "the GUI has a red self-destruct button". Say "the program has a red self-destruct button".

To you, the programmer, it is very important to think about what is part of the GUI and what is not.  However, the user couldn't care less about that.  The interface, by definition, is the only part they see.  The rest is hidden by design.

The only case when the idea of "GUI" might matter to the user is if you have more than one interface.  For example, if you have both a command-line and a graphical interface, you may have to distinguish the two in some contexts.

Still, unless your program is closely tied to the command line, you should probably still not say anything about interfaces in any general documentation or information: just talk about the GUI as "the program" in any generic setting, and put the command line options in the documentation (users who want that will know how to find it--and in that part of the documentation you can probably talk about GUIs without fear of people not knowing what it is).

Comment: +1. I actually missed the fact that to the users, interface *is* the actual program.

Comment: Most users are only exposed to graphical interfaces, so there's no need to differentiate it from commandline or text based.

Comment: @JeffO, thanks, that is what I meant, basically, but I realized that part wasn't completely clear. Edited.

Comment: @MainMa: I would hesitate to paint "the users" with such a broad brush as that. There are many kinds of users. But I would agree that, to most users, the behavior of the interface is what matters, and it's irrelevant how the implementation of that behavior is distributed between various components of the program.

Comment: I know. But in some circumstances you can't get around it and need to say it.

Comment: I would say "program" is the wrong word to choose. When I hear program I think of the code that is executing. In my experience, most people understand the words "app" and "interface".

Comment: @JeffO most users ARE exposed to voice interfaces at some point - Siri or telephone call-tree interfaces. They just don't think of them as interfaces.

Answer (score 28):

I've always just used the term "**screen**" instead of GUI, as in: "Would you like the program to show you the simple screen, or the advanced screen?"

Comment: This is the best answer. In particular, the GUI of a non-windowed embedded system is its "screens". If it's a windowed interface, we can call them windows: the program's collection of windows constitute its user interface.

Comment: Or view, Simple View, advanced View, Customize View etc.. Its simple and everyone understands it.

Comment: When I saw, " synonym for 'GUI' that non-technical people will understand", I thought of Screen and my sister, the epitome of non-technical.  This gets my vote.

Answer (score 5):

You could use "screen layout" as the synonym for Graphical User Interface (GUI). This is easier to understand than the acronym GUI for non technical people. Another alternative would be to spell out the acronym in full wording, and you wouldn´t need a synonym.

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE! Please check out the [faq](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) and [about](http://ux.stackexchange.com/about) pages to learn more about best practices when answering questions. Your answer is a little hard to understand. Providing context (i.e. "A good synonym would be" instead of "it") will help people know what you're trying to say.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer, and upvote your answer at the same time. Welcome to UX.SE ;-)

Comment: @rk. Why does this not provide an answer? I'm asking for a synonym and he/she gives one. Upvoted.

Comment: @com.BOY, this was before the edit by Benny. I upvoted the post after the edit.

Comment: @rk. While before the edit the answer was less easy to understand and less useful, it was still a valid answer, I think.

Comment: @com.BOY I disagreed and raised a flag to draw attention to it. That comment is auto generated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to separate the program from the GUI, then you can use '**Basic interface**' vs '**Advanced interface**'.

If you merge the concerns (program & interface) then you can do what the calculator application on mac and windows does, have **multiple views**, 'basic', 'advanced' and more if need be. You can also link it with **functionality** and say, 'basic functionality' or 'advanced functionality'

Comment: It's not about separating the program from the GUI. For any program to be useful to humans it must have an interface; that interface may be graphical or it may not.

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft bolted a GUI on top of DOS, it's possible that someone on the team point  proposed calling it "Microsoft GUI for DOS", but in the end they came up with "Microsoft Windows".

A program's GUI in a windowed environment is exactly that: it consists of the set of its *windows*. (A generality, with possible exceptions like background programs that have a graphical presence in the form of some icon with a context menu.)

Embedded systems which have graphical (or textual) interfaces without windows, where the pages of the UI occupies a full screen, have *screens*. For example: *This rackmount synthesizer's screens are quite intuitive, making it easy to program*. Or: *Press the Fax button on the copier's main screen to bring up the Fax screen*.

The explanatory help text for newbies that you are looking for might be something like:

> *GUI* stands for Graphical User Interface. It is a visual way of interacting with a computer program by manipulating controls which are represented as diagrams on the screen, and by entering any necessary numbers or text into designated boxes, in any order.
>
> GUIs can be complicated, showing many controls at the same time, including rare features used by experts. A complex GUI overwhelms casual users of a program, or beginners. This program accommodates such users by supporting a mode of operation whereby it presents a simplified form of its GUI that is easier to understand and use for common operations. You can switch to the advanced GUI at any time if you aren't able to find a way to do something using the simple GUI.

Answer (score -2):

"The application's face that you interact with, you can see it, you can transmit informations to it, but it's just the part you see, not the clever part of it, not its brain".